# How can I demonstrate themes well?

Tags: theme-development, multisite, themes

How can I demo Wordpress themes well? I'd like to avoid any undo labour or inefficiency. Perhaps one Wordpress for links to different themes (`example.com/themes`), and each link goes to a second Wordpress that has as theme-switching plugin installed (`demos.example.com/theme-name`). Or is there another way to allow switching themes *and* changing the content of the site depending on whether the visitor is on a demo theme or the main gallery/blog section?

Comment: I have removed the part that asked for a plugin recommendation, because that is off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

Use a multisite installation. Let the main site be your announcement page and at least on sub-site the theme demo site.

Then you can use special content like [WP Test](https://github.com/manovotny/wptest) on that site. Some themes might require special content, like a shop theme that needs products. You can use another, separate sub-site for these themes.